# Do I have one schema or two?

Tags: json, schema, protocol-buffers, database-schema, jsonschema

I have an object type, defined in a JSON schema. I now want to support usage of this object type for users of [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). So, I define this schema again in the Protocol Buffer format.

Do I now have two schemas (a JSON schema and a Protocol Buffer schema), or two formats of one schema?

Comment: What is the point of this question? Why does it matter what it's called?

Comment: I understand why this matters. You now have two schemas. There are some things that can't be expressed in the other schema, and some uses of the schemas that don't apply to the other. Doing this, even if you can find some way to partially automate it, will likely result in a mess at some point. My advice is to pick one and stick with it.